# Undefined function 'ballerina/time:Time.toString'

Tags: string, time, ballerina

I tried to parse string representation into time in ballerina. I referred  https://ballerina.io/learn/api-docs/ballerina/time.html#parse   and https://stagedev.ballerina.io/learn/by-example/date-time.html

Below is the code.

```
time:Time|error t1 = time:parse("2017-06-26T09:46:22.444-0500","yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ");

if (t1 is time:Time){
   io:println("Parsed Time: " + t1.toString());
}
```

Then I got the error `undefined function 'ballerina/time:Time.toString'`

How to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you please share your Ballerina version?

Assuming you are using the latest Ballerina version (0.991.0), it can be done as follows.

```
import ballerina/time;
import ballerina/io;

public function main(string... args) {
    time:Time|error t1 = time:parse("2017-06-26T09:46:22.444-0500",
                                    "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ");

    if (t1 is time:Time){
        io:println("Parsed Time: " + time:toString(t1));
    }
}
```

Complete time example can be found in [Ballerina By Examples](https://ballerina.io/learn/by-example/time.html).

Comment: It is working. But using ```t1.toString()```  as mention in https://stagedev.ballerina.io/learn/by-example/date-time.html  gives the error.

Comment: https://stagedev.ballerina.io/ is not up-to-date with the latest content. So always refer https://ballerina.io/ for updated examples and guides.